# How can I show the time (generated by JavaScript) in a specific div?

Tags: javascript, html, function, time

While learning JavaScript, I found the following code:

```
function printTime() {
  var d = new Date();
  var hours = d.getHours();
  var mins = d.getMinutes();
  var secs = d.getSeconds();
  document.body.innerHTML = hours+":"+mins+":"+secs;
}

setInterval(printTime, 1000);
```

In Codepen this does not show anything while the HTML and CSS sections are empty. The main question is: how can I insert the generated time on a specific place in the HTML document?

For example, the time should be placed in this div:

```
<div id="time" class="main__section--time">
    /* show time here */
</div>
```

How can I link this function to an ID or class to show the output in this div?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to modify your `printTime` function like this:

```
function printTime() {
  var d = new Date();
  var hours = d.getHours();
  var mins = d.getMinutes();
  var secs = d.getSeconds();
  // select the div by its id
  document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = hours+":"+mins+":"+secs;
}
```

Try it in the snippet below:

```js
function printTime() {
  var d = new Date();
  var hours = d.getHours();
  var mins = d.getMinutes();
  var secs = d.getSeconds();
  document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = hours+":"+mins+":"+secs;
}

setInterval(printTime, 1000);
```

```html
<div id="time" class="main__section--time">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `document.body.innerHTML` you would just use `document.getElementById("time").innerHTML`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `document.querySelector` [API](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) together with a [CSS selector](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) to reference a specific element on the page.

```js
var timeDisplayElement = document.querySelector('#my-time');

function printTime() {
  var d = new Date();
  var hours = d.getHours();
  var mins = d.getMinutes();
  var secs = d.getSeconds();
  timeDisplayElement.innerHTML = hours+":"+mins+":"+secs;
}

setInterval(printTime, 1000);
```

```html
<div id="my-time"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = ...`

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the div's id with

> document.getElementById ("time")

And then access to it's innerHTML property

```
function printTime() { 
     var d = new Date(); 
     var hours = d.getHours(); 
     var mins = d.getMinutes(); 
     var secs = d.getSeconds();
     document.body.innerHTML= hours+":"+mins+":"+secs;
}  
 setInterval(printTime, 1000);
```